# I need help with Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan]

Tags: wireless

I have done a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS in a Toshiba A100 Laptop. However the Wireless card doesn't seem to work out-of-the-box. 
It does seem to connect to the network but that is it. I can hardly ping my default gateway.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

my output of some commands:

`lsmod | grep iw`

```
iwl3945                63619  0 
iwlegacy               88016  1 iwl3945
mac80211              546051  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
cfg80211              409394  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211


rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep iw

[   11.258665] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[   11.258670] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   11.258733] iwl3945 0000:05:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   11.317397] iwl3945 0000:05:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[   11.317404] iwl3945 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[   11.317489] iwl3945 0000:05:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.518293] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   23.523343] iwl3945 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to someone with the same problem and the solution that worked: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121599)

Copy/paste of the relevant answer:

`sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ipwraw`

`sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945`

`sudo rm  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf`

```
Add a single line:
Code:
options iwl3945 swcrypto=0
```

Comment: Well i tried that and when I rebooted it started connecting to the wireless network and after a few seconds it says disconnected. Tried it a couple of times and same result.

Comment: I tried adding the lines in /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf:

    `alias wlan0 iwl3045`
and     
    `options iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=1 hwcrypto=1`

as suggested in another post. However this only got my connection working, but the speed was between 0,5 - 1 Mbps.
When its supposed to be aroung 30Mbps via wifi.
Any suggestions?